# Cache Storage com Python

Tags: python, aplicação-web, flask

Estou tentando usar WPA numa aplicação Flask. Gostaria de saber se é possível com o próprio Flask ou Python armazenar minhas páginas no Cache Storage do navegador?

Pelo que vi até agora terei de usar javascript, mas estou tentando evitar para diminuir a complexidade.

Comment: Mas esse *cache storage* que cita não é o do navegador? Se sim, a única forma é com JS. Python só irá atuar no lado do servidor.

Comment: Sim... Do navegador. É que como exite ORM que lida com diversos bancos de dados, pensei que havia algo semelhante, no sentido de dizer o que quero armazenar em cache e ele gerar o .js necessário